# Hide disclosure indicator/arrow in DisclosureGroup

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Does anyone know how to hide or remove the chevron or arrow that appears at the end of a `DisclosureGroup` button?

Answer (score 9):

Try:

```
        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle()).accentColor(.clear).disabled(true)
```

and if you still need to use the button remove the disabled part.

Comment: But `DisclosureGroup` doesn't use `NavigationLink`. Its parameters are `isExpanded`, `content`, and `label`.

Comment: @MaryX check out the answer now, this just worked for me.

Comment: That worked to hide the arrow/chevron but now the group is not expanding and showing the enclosed items. Also I had to set `.disabled` to `true`

Comment: @MaryX, I am not sure I am following the expected functionality maybe? If you need the button to be hidden and work remove the .disabled(true) if you disable it of-course it won't work...

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that I set it to `false`. But when I click the label it does not expand the list of items.

Answer (score 3):

There are two hacky solutions. Make the chevron invisible or cover it. Having it only invisible may have effects like consuming space if you want your label trailing.

**Only hide the chevron:** Make the accentColor clear for the whole disclosure group and make the elements you need colored.

```
DisclosureGroup {
   ...
} label: {
  Text("FooBar").accentColor(.black) // @iOS 15: .tint()
}
.accentColor(.clear) // @iOS 15: .tint()
```

**Cover the chevron:** Important to have the `.withAnimation` and the `VStack`and `HStack` + `Spacer` combinations.

```
@State var isExpanded = false

DisclosureGroup(isExpanded: $isExpanded) {
   ...
} label: {
   label()
}
.overlay(
  VStack {
    HStack {
     label()
    }
    .background(Color.white)
    .onTapGesture { withAnimation { isExpanded.toggle() }}

    Spacer()
  }
)

@ViewBuilder func label() -> some View {
  Text("FooBar")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use `InsetGroupedListStyle()`

```swift
List {
       xxxx
}.listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
```

- [InsetGroupedListStyle | Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/insetgroupedliststyle)